# Turbolinks not working with SVG links

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg, turbolinks

I have a rails app that has an SVG which has some ellipses as links. The links work all right but they don't work with Turbolinks. Normal links work fine with turbolinks. Is there a way to make SVG links work with Turbolinks?

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      height="650px" viewBox="0 0 341.334 532.666" enable-background="new 0 0 341.334 532.666"
     xml:space="preserve" id="map">
 <g id="Layer_2">
    <a xlink:href="/lotes/84" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Lote 84">
        <ellipse fill="none" id="L-84" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="27.833" cy="135.997" rx="23.833" ry="24.333" class="lote "/>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="/lotes/090" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Lote 090">
        <ellipse fill="none" id="L-090" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="74.667" cy="185.831" rx="23" ry="24.167" class="lote Algodon"/>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="/lotes/091" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Lote 091">
        <ellipse fill="none" id="L-091" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="122.833" cy="187.331" rx="23.833" ry="24" class="lote Algodon"/>
    </a>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just [opened an issue](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/654) for this. In the meantime, with Turbolinks 3 (not sure about 2), you can manage a workaround with `Turbolinks.visit()`.

**With jQuery:**

```
$('svg a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  Turbolinks.visit( this.getAttribute('href') );
});
```

**With D3:**

```
svg.selectAll('a')
  .on('click', function() {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    Turbolinks.visit( 
      d3.select(this).node().getAttribute('href')
    );
  });
```